# Почему файл остается пустым?

Tags: python, файлы

В первом файле находится: a3b4c2e10b1 Во второй должно записаться: aaabbbbcceeeeeeeeeeb

```
import re
my_str=''
with open ('dataset_3363_2.txt') as file_in, open("1.txt", 'w') as file_out:
    for el in re.findall(r'(\w)(\d+)', file_in):
        my_str += el[0]*int(el[1])
file_out.write(my_str)
```

Answer (score 0):

Потому что write после закрытия файла. Поместите его под open

Answer (score 0):

https://repl.it/repls/DeliciousDirectSection

```
import re
my_str=''
with open ('dataset_3363_2.txt') as file_in, open("1.txt", 'w') as file_out:
    for el in re.findall(r'(\w)(\d+)', file_in.read()):
        my_str += el[0]*int(el[1])
    file_out.write(my_str)
```

Comment: все равно пустым остается

Comment: @PuhoviyLw вы по ссылке переходили? Там полный файл почему-то